# Nodejs Express multi category route schema

Tags: node.js, express

I list the articles under the **category**. but there are more than one **subcategory**. I want to write these together in connection. I also want the page number in the form of `/page/2`. What kind of schema should I use here.

> This is the current route. But isn't work

```
([a-z0-9-_/]+/)?:slug([0-9a-z-_]+)(/page/:page([0-9]+))?$
```

> Link structure

```
category/[category]/[sub]/[sub-sub]/page/[number]
```

> Sample Link

```
category/language/mobile/swift/page/2
```

And I want the last subcategory name. `(swift)`

Comment: Is there a limit to how many subcategories there are? Is `category`, `sub` and `sub-sub` always present in this route? Is a route like `category/[category]/page/[number]` valid? Does this route handle all of the steps from the subcategories?

Comment: No sub-category limit. It can only come in the top category. Or in all other sub-categories.

`category/[category]/page/[number]` are valid.